# Prove that representations of G over F form a ring

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras, riesz-representation-theorem

I am trying to solve the question: Representations of a group G over a field F form a ring R.
Am I supposed to use something like Grothendieck rings or I don't know?

Comment: The elements of $F[G]$ are formal sums of the form $\sum_{g \in G} f_g g$ with $f_g \in F$. Define a suitable sum and product and turn the crank.

Comment: The actual representations won't constitute a ring, because additive inverses are missing. Also, whoever asked you this question probably meant to consider isomorphic representations to be the same (i.e., to work not with representations but with isomorphism classes thereof).  With those changes, you should get a ring if $F$ has characteristic 0 or prime characteristic not dividing the order of $G$. Otherwise, I think more identifications are needed; for any exact sequence $0\to A\to B\to C\to0$, you probably need to identify $B$ with $A+C$.

Comment: To say that some set "forms a ring" is bad (albeit, unfortunately, common) language. Your source should either define the operations addition and multiplication or make clear that it's your task to define them in a reasonable way. Additionally, "the" (=all) representations are not even a set, but a proper class, i.e. there is an annoying set-theoretic issue here.

Comment: I would interpret that in terms of Grothendieck groups or Grothendieck rings, where the class $[V]$ of a representation is equal to $[U]  + [W]$ whenever there exists a short exact sequence $0 \to U \to V \to W \to 0$. You will need to make sure that direct sum and tensor products of representations descend to operations with the correct properties on the linear span of the $[V]$.